# How do I run neo4j shell with chinese unicode UTF8 characters?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to run a script full of Cypher queries which contain Chinese characters.

The powershell in windows 10 does not let me enter the shell to run the scripts.

1) running with the -f option gets stuck
2) using power shell with ISE can read Chinese characters, but when I launch neo4j-shell the shell gets stuck and never reaches the prompt.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opened up the files in notepad++ and converted all the text to UTF-8 format (no BOM).

Saved the files again and then ran the cypher load csv scripts:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///stuff.out" AS row
```